# Is "Part Decomposition" supported in EA?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to draw a [part decomposition diagram](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_sequencediagram.html) with EA10. It should look like below.

[image]

But I couldn't find how. Is this UML diagram ever supported by EA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. I need to activate the "More tools..." -> "Composite" first. And choose "Port".

BTW, this is really a bad user experience.

[image]

Comment: Just logging that corresponding help file link seems to be http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/modeling_basics/compositegroup.html. BTW: yes, designing complex UI and writing complex documentation is always _challenge_ even in a product developed for [14 (or 18?) years](http://www.sparxsystems.com/about.html) in a team of engineers (and probably system architect, UX architect and accepted UI standards changed several times during this period, not even trying to think about the fat product backlogs)

Comment: 10 years ago or so I called that EAUI - EA Unique Interface. It's up to you how you interpret Unique ;-)

Comment: I have to say, EA is a comprehensive tool. And it is very powerful. But it takes some time to get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong. Sorry, but there's no kinder way to say it. :)

If the lifeline (`:Class`) is associated with a classifier (`Class`) which has properly defined ports (as it should be), then the following applies:

1. If you create the lifeline by dropping the classifier onto the sequence diagram, you get the option of displaying the ports (aka "structural elements") immediately.
2. Regardless of how the lifeline was created, you can right-click it and select "Structural Elements" which allows you to select the ports from the classifier (which may have been added since the lifeline was created).

If you want to create ports under a lifeline which has no classifier, you can do that too. Simply right-click and select "Structural Elements". The dialog allows you to create new ports.

Comment: This is really the same as what @chimp is saying, just a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

The **:Class** lifeline presumably gets its type information from a **Class** element, so the first thing you need to do is find the **Class** element and give it two ports. Once you have done that, you can right-click the lifeline, select the Embedded Elements dialog and include the ports on the lifeline. (The Embedded Elements dialog may have been renamed Structural Elements in recent versions).